# How does IDENT work?

Tags: air-traffic-control, transponder

In order to help ATC identify an aircraft on their screen, they may ask the aircraft to "ident." The pilot presses a button on their transponder, and the controller can verify that the aircraft they are talking to is the one they are looking at on the screen.

- In what situations does ATC ask for ident, and is it ever required by procedure?
- What does the transponder actually do in this mode?
- What does the controller see on their screen?
- Does it depend at all on either the code or the mode the transponder is currently set for?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

(Note: This answer is tailored to the U.S. / FAA, because that is what I'm familiar with. All the citations and references are FAA materials. If anyone has any tips on possible international differences, please let me know and I'll edit them in. That said, I believe the *descriptions* I give are fairly consistent across the world, even if the FAA reg citations don't directly apply.)

> **In what situations does ATC ask for ident, and is it ever required by procedure?**

Generally, "ident" is used to help a controller identify an aircraft's secondary radar (transponder) return. By asking the pilot to "squawk ident," the controller can ensure that the aircraft he/she is talking to matches the radar target he thinks is that aircraft.

It can also be used for communication, to allow a pilot to respond if their radio transmitter has failed.

Specifically:

- It is a method to allow a controller to identify an aircraft on radar, per section 5-3-3 of [FAA Order 7110.65 (pdf)](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/orders_notices/index.cfm/go/document.current/documentNumber/7110.65):

> When using only Mode 3/A radar beacon to identify a target, use one of the following methods:
>
> **a.** Request the aircraft to activate the "IDENT" feature of the transponder and then observe the identification display.

- For lost communication, per section 10-4-4 of [7110.65](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/orders_notices/index.cfm/go/document.current/documentNumber/7110.65):

> Take the following actions, as appropriate, if two-way radio communications are lost with an aircraft:
>
> **c.** Attempt to re-establish communication by having the aircraft use its transponder or make turns to acknowledge clearances and answer questions. Request any of the following in using the transponder:
>
> **1.** Request the aircraft to reply Mode 3/A “IDENT.”

This last scenario is common when experiencing radio failures. If ATC suspects that you might be able to *hear* them but not to talk back, they might say something like "Cessna 12345, if you can hear me, squawk ident." If you reply by pressing the IDENT button, they can then issue you further instructions and ask you to acknowledge those instructions by pressing IDENT again.

---

> **What does the transponder actually do in this mode?**

In normal operation, every time the transponder receives an *interrogation* from a ground station, it replies with a data block containing certain pieces of information. [This data block contains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transponder_%28aviation%29#Ident):

- The encoded pressure altitude (for Mode C transponders)
- A 12-bit identification code (this is the 4-digit code you select in the cockpit)
- A single extra bit for the "ident" flag

When you push the IDENT button in the cockpit, the transponder sets that extra "ident" bit in its reply data. Anytime the transponder is interrogated while IDENT is active (for a set duration of time after you press the button in the cockpit), its reply data block will have the IDENT bit set. ATC computer systems notice this and cause the IDENT to be shown on the controller's radar display.

---

> **What does the controller see on their screen?**

It depends on the type of radar system in use. Generally the radar target will either blink, its symbol will change (or "blossom"), or an indication such as "ID" will blink in the aircraft's data block (where the callsign is shown).

The AIM has some schematic pictures that show what an IDENT looks like on an ARTS-III scope (an older system still in use at some TRACONs). See [Figures 4-5-2](http://www.faraim.org/aim/aim-4-03-14-229.html) and [4-5-3](http://www.faraim.org/aim/aim-4-03-14-231.html).

I will try to find some pictures of other radar systems such as those used at ARTCCs and newer TRACONs.

---

> **Does it depend at all on either the code or the mode the transponder is currently set for?**

The code doesn't matter. The IDENT flag is an extra bit in the transponder's reply data that's independent of the 12 bits used for the code.

Obviously the IDENT will only be observed if the transponder is operating (not OFF or in a STANDBY mode). But the IDENT works in any mode used by normal civilian transponders (Modes A, C or S).

Comment: Wait, so does this mean simply pressing the button will not ident... the operator must HOLD the button until the transponder is next interrogated. That may be several seconds! That would explain why I always had so much trouble with this.

Comment: @DouglasHeld No, you don't need to hold the button. Pushing IDENT puts the transponder into a special mode for a specific amount of time. Any interrogation replies it sends during that time will have the ident flag set.

Comment: @Zaz I replaced all of the dead FAA.gov links. Unfortunately, I only found a PDF version of 7110.65 on the FAA's website now. If there's an HTML version somewhere, that would probably be a better link. For the AIM, I linked to faraim.org, which has an HTML version of the AIM, since I again only found a PDF version on the actual FAA website.

Comment: Where is the 18 second IDENT time duration specified? I see the specifications in most transponders use this value however I have been unable to find an FAA or other governing body which specifies either a range or the 18 second value.

Comment: @TypeIA figure links are failing...

Answer (score 5):

> In what situations does ATC ask for ident, and is it ever required by procedure?

ATC asks a pilot to IDENT for identification purposes. If used, it usually on first (secondary) radar contact. Identification can be done by other means as well, for example by identifying turns, correlation to reported position etc.

See this [FAA document](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/ATpubs/ATC/atc0503.html) for how radar identification can be done by means of IDENT or otherwise.

> What does the transponder actually do in this mode?

The transponder will, for a duration of 18 seconds after IDENT is pressed, change its reply to radar interrogations.

If the interrogation is a Mode A or Mode C interrogation, an additional pulse is appended 4.35 microseconds after the last framing pulse of the standard Mode A/C reply. This is called the SPI (special purpose identification) pulse.

If the interrogation is a Mode S interrogation (Uplink Format 4,5, 20 or 21) and the transponder is a Mode S transponder, the Flight Status field in the reply will be set to indicate that Ident is pressed.

If the Mode S transponder is transmitting ADS-B as well, the Surveillance Status field in the position messages will be set to indicate that Ident is pressed. This is also done for 18 seconds after the IDENT button is pressed.

> What does the controller see on their screen?

The controller will see an indication that the aircraft is IDENTifiying. In what form the indication is presented depends on the ATC system. For example, the data block may be flashing, boxed, or (partly) highlighted.

> Does it depend at all on either the code or the mode the transponder is currently set for?

No, IDENT is independent of the Mode A code (squawk code) set in the transponder.

Answer (score 1):

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transponder_%28aviation%29#Ident) (*emphasis mine*):

> All mode A, C, and S transponders include an "IDENT" button, which **activates a special thirteenth bit on the mode A reply known as IDENT**, short for "identify"". When ground-based radar equipment receives the IDENT bit, it results in the aircraft's blip "blossoming" on the radar scope. This is often used by the controller to locate the aircraft amongst others by requesting the ident function from the pilot, e.g., "Cessna 123AB, squawk 0363 and ident".

In my limited experience, the time I had to IDENT was in crowded traffic so the controller could identify me. How it was explained to me (and I can't find an exact description for blossoming) was that the blip on ATC's screen that is you will "pulse", sending out concentric circles for a few seconds. It makes it very obvious which craft is sending out the IDENT. [This article](http://www.avweb.com/news/avionics/183231-1.html?redirected=1) gives a brief, slightly different description:

> When you push the IDENT button, it adds an extra pulse to your replies that causes your target on the controller's radar scope to change appearance. (It either "blooms" on an approach control radar screen, or has a flashing "ID" on a center radar screen.) Controllers sometimes use this to help find your target, or to make sure the target they think is you really is.